# Authentication via Facebook in a cross platform unity3d application

Tags: facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am working on a game in Unity3D (version 4.3.4) which I want to build to mobile platfroms Android and iOS. I am trying to make the login via Facebook. I have downloaded and imported Facebook SDK for Unity (5.0.4) into my Unity project. I have also made all the prerequsities for autheticating a unity3d game via facebook sdk (register app on FB dev website, added the app id to unity project and wrote the code for FB.Login, which is in the documentation of the Facebook SDK for Unity).
When I ran the app in Unity3D editor, everything is working (DLL is loaded, facebook window popups...), but when I build the Unity app to any kind of platform (android, iOS, desktop, web...) and I open the game, then the Facebook SDK is not loaded anymore, authentification is not working. I have found the next error: "Facebook Dll: Not Loaded". Maybe this can cause the problem (and maybe some other things), I dont know.

I have tried everything. I found on the web that there can be a version problem with Unity3D and with the SDK, so I tried to build the project with older version of Unity3D (4.2.2) and with older version of Facebook SDK for Unity (4.3.3) but nothing helped.

Please help me If you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also fill out the required fields for Android and iOS in the developers.facebook.com/apps.  You need to add a platform for them and fill in the Bundle Identifier (aka Package Name) and the Class name.

Also the SDK doesn't support Desktop and only supports web if your app is on Facebook Canvas.

Comment: Yeh resolved. My problem was that I was testing the app with the sdk as a desktop app which is not supported, but this fact is not present in the sdk documentation. On iOS is working well.